# Can you add sorting and filtering to SharePoint List views using the send http to sharepoint/rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, sharepoint-rest-api, flow, power-automate

I am trying to create a list view with sorting and filtering on using the SP rest API and send http to SharePoint action.

I have added a CAML query to the View Query parameter in the body of the send http to SharePoint action. The power automate runs successfully and creates the view but when I go into SharePoint and look at modifying the view, I can see that no sorting or filtering has been applied.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the current CAML query you have for your list view configuration? Also, check configuration/code in [this thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Creating-a-SharePoint-view-from-Power-Automate/td-p/607201) if it helps.

Comment: @GaneshSanap sure, see below.

'ViewQuery':'<Where><Neq><FieldRef Name="ColumnName" /><Value Type="Text"></Value></Neq></Where>'

The aim of the filter is to display items where column name is not empty, is there a better way of doing this using CAML?